# Pipeline: .NetCoreCLI Test Task throws non-zero error

Tags: unit-testing, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, code-coverage, xunit

I have used the following yml command for my .Net 5 API project and xUnit Test Project but it throws error and my pipeline is not getting succeeded. Where did I go wrong?

Note: The pipeline is not getting succeded even if the task executed the test cases and showing 15 test cases passed and 2 test cases are filed.

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
   inputs:
       command: 'restore'
       projects: '**/GeniusData.Test/GeniusData.Test.csproj'
     displayName: 'Restore Projects'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
 inputs:
  command: test
  projects: '**/*Test/*.csproj'
  arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration) --collect "Code coverage"'
 displayName: 'Test Project'
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the `DotNetCoreCLI@2` task which will always fail when tests fail. That's by design: failing tests should break the build.

Comment: You shouldn’t need to have a manual publish step if you’re using the Azure Devops dotnet task. It pushes it to the test results screen by default.

Comment: You are correct! And the screenshot shows that test results were published. I'll update my answer.

Comment: @bryanbcook thank you for your comment but no luck after 100% success test cases too. It throws the same error with other .Net Core version also

Comment: @bryanbcook Hey I did refresh the pipelines yml file and then solution then tried it worked. So agree with you that failed test cases should not be there for DotNetCoreCLI2 test settings. Thank you.